# Ruby: How to check that all elements in array are negative integers

Tags: ruby

I have the arrays `a = [-1,-2,-3,-4]` and `b = [-1,-2,-3,4]`

How can I make sure that `a` contains only negative integers? 
I can check that some of elements are negative `a.select(&:negative?) == true` and `b.select(&:negative?) == true`

But I need to know that `b.select(&:negative?).only == true`

Comment: Can the array contain elements that are not integers (e.g, "cat")?

Comment: In my case - no, but I think the solution with other types of elements will be interesting to all.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". Instead of asking us all the ways to do it, which is too broad, instead you should ask a specific question about how you did it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [Enumerable#`all?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F) here:

```
[-1,-2,-3,-4].all?(&:negative?)
#=> true
```

Btw, I think you are confused with what is happening here:

```
a.select(&:negative?) == true
```

This is not checking whether all elements are negative. What it is in fact is comparing resulting array of negative numbers with `false`:

```
[-1,-2,-3,-4] == false
```

Of course, it will always return `false`, because only `false` is equal to `false`.

Comment: Instead of `.find`, it's better to use `.any?` here :) `a.any?(&:positive?)` or `a.none?(&:negative?)`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I think `find` will work best here, since will stop iterating once find a positive number. Or is `any?`'s underhood faster?

Comment: `.any?` short-circuits too, of course. And it reads better. You know, revealing intention, all that.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev agree, `any?` reveals the intention better. Thanks for commenting!

Answer (score 6):

You could simply consider the largest value:

```
arr = [-1,-2,-3,-4]
arr.empty? ? false : arr.max < 0
  #=> true
```

if the array contains only integers. If the array may contain elements that are not integers, one must first confirm that only integers are present.

```
arr = [-1,-2,-3,-4, "cat", { a:1 }]
return false unless arr.all? { |e| e.is_a?(Fixnum) }
  #=> false returned
```

Comment: This is great answer!

Comment: @KirillZhuravlov I noticed, you almost never accepted an answer to any of your questions. Please, walk through your past questions and make sure to checkmark the answers, that solved your problems, this way you let the community know that the issue is solved and, also, reward the effort of the user who has given this answer.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko thank you to your notice, I did it as you suggest.